# How i can do modulus of _id field in mongoDb, when _id is object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We have email sending firm, In that, I  want to send emails to half of the guys with **template A** and half of the guys with **template B**. I want to get this division of subscribers on a random basis, not by date or something and I want to restrict sending both the email to the same email id.

I have one field email_hash in the database which is Hexadecimal so, I cannot able to apply `$mod[2,0]` in that field to bifurcate the subscribers.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
   {
    _id: Object("adhgadh67u7y"),
    email: "abc@example.com",
    email_hash: "c4adccb9a9a7333e6d7a206739f1f624413a38ac70f54d77e89d3c404bef7c3d",
    created_date: ISoDate("some date"),
    updated_date: ISoDate("some date"),
    name: "some name"

   }
```

Comment: What is the schema for your this document, are you storing email_hash as string?

Comment: yes we are storing email_hash as sha256 of email as a string